# Can systems of set relations always be simplified to a canonical form?

Tags: set-theory

For example, $(A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A)$ can be trivially reduced to $(A=B)$.  Or $(A\subseteq B$, $B\subseteq C$, and $C\subseteq A)$ can be reduced to equality of all three.

But is it always possible to for any system of relations to reduce it to some "canonical" form, whatever that may be?  Such that if there are two equivalent systems, they'd reduce to the same form?  If so, is there an efficient algorithm to do so?

Alternatively, what I *really* want to know, is there any algorithm to determine whether two systems of relations, e.g. $(A\subseteq B\subseteq C\subseteq A)$ and $(A\supseteq B\supseteq C\supseteq A)$ are equivalent to each other?  The only operations I'm concerned about are sub/superset (not proper), intersection, and union.

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ can be considered as an abbreviation for the "canonical"  $\forall x\,(x\in A \implies x\in B)$... The axiom of Extensionality is $A=B\iff (\forall x\,(x\in A\iff x\in B)$... (applied to every $A,B$ )... which can be abbreviated as $A=B\iff (A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq A),$ or, if you like, $A=B\iff A\subseteq B\subseteq A$.... We can prove that $\subseteq$ is transitive : $A\subseteq B\subseteq C\implies A\subset C$, which can be applied to improve  efficiency

Comment: BTW the modern style is that $A\subset B$  means the same thing as $A\subseteq B$ . And to denote that $A$ is a proper subset of $B,$ write $A\subsetneq B$ or $A\subsetneqq B$ . ("\subsetneq" or "\subsetneqq").